# What makes ByteString IO so fast?

Tags: bytestring, haskell

I've been trying to solve [problem 1330](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1330&locale=en) from acm.timus.ru in Haskell. Basically, it boils down to this: 1) read from stdin an array A of length N (N < 10^4) and M pairs of integers (M < 10^5); 2) for each (from, to) pair, print the sum of subarray A[from..to] to stdout.

Since SO won't let me post more than 2 URLs as part of this question, I will refer to files in my [Github repository](https://github.com/dfyz/stuff/tree/master/1330) below.

I came up with two solutions, which share most of the code. The first one (1330_slow.hs) uses Prelude functions (getLine/read/words) and is somewhat slow:

```
$ ./bench.sh slow_hs
slow_hs
    Time inside the program: 2.18
MD5 (output.slow_hs.txt) = 89bcf8fd69a7fce953595d329c8f033a
```

The other solution (1330.hs) ditches these functions, replacing them with their Data.ByteString.Char8 equivalents (B.getLine/B.readInt/B.words), and performs decently well:

```
$ ./bench.sh hs
hs
    Time inside the program: 0.27
MD5 (output.hs.txt) = 89bcf8fd69a7fce953595d329c8f033a
```

The time limit on this problem is 500 ms, so while 270 ms is fast enough (and comparable to my solutions in other languages, such as C++ and Go), 2180 ms doesn't cut it. So why is my first solution so ridiculously slow? Even by following the profiling tips from Real World Haskell I still can't make sense of this (all I could figure out was that the majority of time was spent in readIntPair function, which didn't help much).

If you want to do some testing of your own, I have a Python input generator (gen_test.py), and a pre-generated input file (input.txt) in case you don't have Python installed. And a diff (slow_fast_diff.txt) between the two solutions.

Comment: I am probably way over my head here, but can you try Data.ByteString.Lazy? I think the slow example is somehow lazy?

Comment: @GertCuykens It might be more useful to ask "why is the non-bytestring version so slow?" For anything that requires a high throughput, the default string type will be horribly slow, as it is implemented as a linked list of unicode character. Laziness is more a result of this implementation of strings, which has the consequence of a lot of allocations and pointer indirections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have said, it's not that `ByteString` is fast, it's that `String` is very, very slow.

A `ByteString` stores one byte per character, plus some book-keeping overhead. A `String` stores something like 12 bytes per character (depending on whether you're running in 32-bit or 64-bit mode). It also stores each character in non-contiguous memory, so each character has to have space individually allocated to it, individually scanned by the garbage collector, and eventually individually deallocated again. This means poor cache locality, lots of allocator time, and lots of garbage collection time. In short, it's hellishly inefficient.

Basically, `ByteString` does what C does, what Java does, what C++ does, what C# does, what VB does, and what just about every other programming language does with strings. No other language I'm aware of has a default string type as inefficient as Haskell does. (Even Frege, which is a Haskell dialect, uses a more efficient string type.)

I should point out that `ByteString.Char8` only handles Latin-1 characters. It doesn't cope with random Unicode characters at all. That probably isn't a problem for a programming challenge like this, but for a "real system" it might well be. `ByteString` doesn't really deal with exotic characters or different character encodings or anything; it just assumes you want plain ASCII. That used to be a safe assumption; today, not so much.

Comment: just would add there is `Data.ByteString.UTF8` module (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string) to handle unicode characters (subset of them) which is still magnitude faster then default String type.

Comment: @DavidUnric Yes, there are several packages for handling Unicode properly and still with high performance. Basically if you use anything *other* than `String`, you should be golden.

Comment: How about Erlang strings? They're quite like Haskell's ones too.

Comment: And notice two years later the `text` package has dominated the world of (Haskell) text processing in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 8):

### Contrasting ByteString and String (i.e. Why is String slow?)

`Bytestring` IO involves reading data into packed buffers, just like you might be used to in C.  `String`s, on the other hand, are linked lists of characters which not only complicates IO but for processing this can mean higher usage of memory, processing, cache, perhaps branching, and GC.

### Why is ByteString fast?

Another way to phrase it: `ByteString` is fast for the same reasons `unsigned char *`
is fast in `C`.

Comment: `ByteString` isn't like C's `unsigned char *`, but rather, like Java `String`.  C strings are 0-terminated `char` sequences, while Haskell `ByteString`s are byte array + start index into the array + length.  This can potentially be *faster* than C strings, because it's possible to (a) know the length of the string without scanning it, and (b) take substrings without copying the contents.

Comment: Yep.  It's just a rough analogy and overwhelmingly true (In many cases, most the performance benefit vs String is because the data is in a contiguous buffer).